# ISAM error:record is locked

Tags: sql, locking, informix

Could someone help me to reproduce SQL exception: Could not do a physical-order read to fetch next row, ISAM error:record is locked ?

Comment: Did you manage to accomplish what you wanted?

Comment: I tried your answer and I got the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

In session 1:

```
BEGIN WORK;
LOCK TABLE YOURTABLE IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;
```

Don't COMMIT nor ROLLBACK for now;

In session 2:

```
SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE;
```

This should result in that error.

After this you should do ROLLBACK WORK in session 1.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to trigger it;

```
SET ISOLATION TO REPEATABLE READ;

SELECT * FROM __table__;
```

Then in another session:

```
SELECT * FROM __table__
```

The error is caused when a row (or page) in your table is locked by another process.